# How to fix Angular 13 (peer) dependency error on npm install?

Tags: angular, npm, dependencies, agm

I'm developing a Angular component library and since the update to Angular 13 we have some errors during `npm i @our/library@14.1.1-beta.1` of our library:

```
npm ERR! While resolving: test-app@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@13.2.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~13.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0" from @agm/core@1.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@agm/core
npm ERR!   peer @agm/core@"^1.1.0" from @our/library@14.1.1-beta.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@our/library
npm ERR!     @our/library@"14.1.1-beta.1" from the root project
```

So it seems to me that `@agm/core@1.1.0` has `@angular/common@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0"` as a dependency which is not compatible with `@angular/common@"~13.2.0"`. Is that correct?

I tried to add `@angular/common@8.0.0` as a dependency to our library, but that didn't do a thing, the error on install still exists.

Install works with the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag but it sounds like that is not the correct way to install.
I use npm v8.5.0 and node v14.18.2.

So is there a solution for that apart deleting `@agm/core` and use something different?

Answer (score -4):

Running `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` will fix an error. Actually, some of the dependencies are not compatible with the newer/older angular versions. Installing peer deps install the necessary dependency to work. It installs a dependency locally for the particular plugin, not for the application.

Comment: Hi, How do you do for build:prod... for you FTP enterprise... ? -_- npm install --force ....

Comment: Please do not post comments/answers that leads to more problems than solutions. Force flag is never recommended.